# Double Tax - U.K. resident US citizen

Tags: taxes

Let’s say I am American citizen and a U.K. resident. I have businesses registered in both countries.

Is my US income taxable in both the US and the U.K. in this scenario?

Any replies would be greatly appreciated as I’ve found information online a little confusing.

Comment: This way too short to be an answerable question. You need to hire a firm that specializes in US & UK taxation, there are several good ones. Especially if business entities are involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The details of this are complicated. Let me give you the short general answer.

Your income is theoretically taxable in both countries. You have to file tax returns in both countries, and in both you have to declare all of your worldwide income. As a US citizen you always have to file a US tax return, unless your total worldwide income is so low as to exempt you.

There is a **double tax treaty** between the UK and the US which means you should not end up paying twice as much tax. It's complicated and it would probably be best to get a tax accountant familiar with both countries.